# Retrieving HTML from ASP.NET page on postback

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I've found a few posts about retrieving HTML from an ASPX page, mostly by overriding the render method, using a WebClient, or creating an HttpWebRequest. All these methods return the HTML of the page as it's loaded, but I was hoping to actually retrieve the HTML after the user has entered information.
The purpose behind this is that I work in IT, and I'm attempting to build a logging library that has an overload that essentially does a "screen-scrape" on the page just as the user encounters an exception, that way I can log the exception, and create an HTML file in a sub-directory of the logging directory that shows the page exactly as the user had it before clicking "submit" or having some other random error, and add an "ID" to the error that's logged telling whoever is fixing the issue which page to look at.

I hope I've provided enough information, because I really have no idea where to start.

Also, We'd like to do this through our own library, because our logging library is included in our common library, and many of our common library functions use our logging class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm...

If you want to see what the user sees after they've been using the page, you're most likely going to have to do some fancy client-side scripting.

A naive approach:

When the clicks the submit button, fire a JavaScript event that encodes the DOM and either passes it as a form variable to the server, or executes a separate AJAX request with the encoded data as a parameter. ("Encode" in this case may be as simple as grabbing document.innerHtml, but I haven't checked.)

This potentially introduces a **lot** of overhead to every form submission, so I'd keep it out of production code.

I'm not sure why you need the rendered HTML as part of your exception log - I've never found it necessary for server-side debugging.

Comment: It's not meant for every form submission, only when an exception occurs, and only for the exceptions we choose to use it on. Also, it's not included in the log, but rather in individual HTML files in a sub-directory of the logging directory. I'll look into using javascript (kinda figured I would have to), but thought I'd see if there's a .NET method to do it first.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't tell if a server-side exception occurred until you're executing on the server, at which point you either have all the data you want for logging, or not. You'd have to send it with every request. You can't go back to the browser after an exception occurred and ask for the HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to go the javascript route. I like javascript, but hate trying to pass variables between javascript and ASP.NET.

Comment: Just add a hidden form field in your ASPX and set its value to the HTML string in the form's submit method. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yea, but this is in a generic library. I don't like telling people to add items to their page in order to use the library correctly.

Comment: You can add the hidden field to the page dynamically when your exception handler runs.You would need to make the field name unlikely to used by other code and document it for users of your library in the section describing your exception logging feature.

Answer (score 0):

You getting HTML code from a website. You can use code like this.

```
string urlAddress = "http://www.jobdoor.in";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader readStream = null;
  if (response.CharacterSet == null)
  readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
  else
  readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
  string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
  response.Close();
  readStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're missing the point of the question.